# How to run premade javascript files in a website?

Tags: javascript, html, godot

> I do have simple coding skills. I don't know too much about web development, only the very basics. I usually code in python and never have to use JavaScript or HTML.

So I made a game using Godot. And I exported my game with the html5 export.

It gave me

- index.html
- index.js
- index.pck
- index.wasm
- favicon and PNG

I uploaded my game on itch.io, and they just needed a zip file of the above, but now I want to host the game on my own website.

I want to know the both methods of running the code in a small box on the website kind of like how it plays on itch and a way of playing just the app on the whole web page.

Likewise, I did try to research this online, but currently what I lack is how to describe this issue? Because all I search is how to run index.html file or how to implement that HTML in another HTML.

Which as you can guess gave me varied results from which none of them solved the issue and I realized that describing my issue here would be the best thing to do.

> Oh, and I'm not going to make only games, so please don't give an answer that works specifically for games.

Comment: Based on the list of files it looks like all you need is to statically host all of the files and it will work. Have you tried using GitHub Pages to host the game?

Comment: When I wanted to test my game HTML exports I used xampp. Any web server will do, as the Godot HTML exports run entirely on the client side, you don't need a server that supports any particular server side technology, language or platform. You can, for example, get a free PHP hosting and just upload those files (you don't need PHP, I only mention it because PHP hosting is ubiquitous, so you would have no problem getting such hosting). You can, of course, modify the html file (and add css) to change how the page is presented, but that is more web development than game development.

Answer (score 0):

As you code in python you should know that you can start a local web server in python for testing purposes.

You can start a server by running the command in the directory where all the files for game are located

```
python -m http.server 80
```

Where **80** is the port

And navigate to **localhost:[port]** in your browser

And to stop the server just press **ctrl + c** in terminal